# PHP Fatal error when installing mcrypt

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, php7

I am installing the mcrypt extension.
After running the command `sudo pecl install mcrypt-1.0.1`, the following error shows:

> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use result of built-in function in write context in /usr/share/php/Archive/Tar.php on line 639

[image: Screenshot]

Please help!

Comment: Can we see more of the error copied and pasted into your question?